# Generar una nueva columna en base a varias condiciones R

Tags: r, rstudio, r-dplyr

Tengo una base de datos la cual tengo varias filas por especie, en algunos casos puede ser una sola pero en otros pueden ser 2 o mas.
Quiero generar una nueva columna para que si se cumplen las condiciones, poner un nombre.

He intentado agrupar por `codigo_id` unico para luego con `mutate` generar la nueva columna, pero no me funciona, si elijo una sola condicion si, pero parece que no esta funcionando el `group_by`

```
estratos= DATOS_IFN3 %>%
  select(1:10, Codigo_id)%>%
  group_by(Codigo_id)%>%
  mutate(test1 = case_when(Especie_num == "45" & Especie_num == "26"  ~ "X"))
```

Pongo un ej de mi df, si ven el `Codigo_id` es 232A1, que se repite en mis primeras 5 filas, por lo que en esas filas tengo varias `Especies_sp`, manualmente le asigne un X en la columna `Estrato` ya que esa combiancion de Especies asi lo codifica.

Quiero generar un `case_when` o algo para que lea por grupos `Codigo_id` y me asigne ese valor, alguna ayuda?

```
 head(estratos)
# A tibble: 6 x 11
# Groups:   Codigo_id [2]
  Estrato...1 Provincia Estadillo Cla   Subclase CoordX  CoordY Especie_sp      Estrato...9 Especie_num Codigo_id
        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>           <chr>             <dbl> <chr>    
1          15        23         2 A     1        535000 4262000 Pinus pinaster  X                    26 232A1    
2          15        23         2 A     1        535000 4262000 Quercus faginea X                    44 232A1    
3          15        23         2 A     1        535000 4262000 Quercus faginea X                    44 232A1    
4          15        23         2 A     1        535000 4262000 Quercus ilex    X                    45 232A1    
5          15        23         2 A     1        535000 4262000 Quercus ilex    X                    45 232A1    
6          18        23         3 A     1        389000 4250000 Quercus ilex    III                  45 233A1
```

Comment: No sé si entendí bien tu planteo, si quieres codificar en base al `Codigo_id` debrías: 1) quitar el `group_by()` 2) hacer que  `Codigo_id` participe del `case_when()). Por ejemplo: `case_when(Codigo_id = '232A1' & (Especie_num == "45" & Especie_num == "26")  ~ "X")`

Comment: Hola Patricio, en realidad no sé si eso es viable porque el Codigo_id va cambiando. Son parcelas de varias especies de árboles y a veces es solo una especie y le pongo el código F por ej pero si son varias como el ejemplo le pongo X.  Entonces por eso quise agrupar por Codigoid que sería la parcela.

Comment: O sea si en un codigo_id tienes más de una especie, quieres que todo el grupo sea X pero si el codigo_id tiene una sola especie, el grupo debería ser  F, ¿es así?

Comment: Exacto, lo simplifique a 2 grupos aunque tengo más. Pero con un ejemplo yo puedo armar el resto.  Las especies van cambiado pero la idea es poner por fila que tiene el mismo codigo-id el mismo grupo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es contar las cantidad de especies por `Codigo_id`:

```
DATOS_IFN3 %>%
  group_by(Codigo_id) %>%
  summarise(especies = n_distinct(Especie_sp ))
```

Ahora, simplemente hay que unir esta consulta a cada fila según su `Codigo_id` y  elaborar la condición para el `mutate()`:

```
DATOS_IFN3 %>% 
  left_join(DATOS_IFN3 %>%
              group_by(Codigo_id) %>%
              summarise(especies = n_distinct(Especie_sp )),
            by = "Codigo_id") %>% 
  mutate(test1 = if_else(especies > 1, 'X', 'F'))
```

Comment: Hola Patricio, gracias por tu respuesta. He generado otra pregunta explicandome mejor aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/570280/asignar-el-resultado-de-un-case-when-a-todas-las-filas-definido-por-group-by-r.  De todas formas tu respuesta me ayudo con otro problema que tenia, justamente era el conteo